# UIImageView setImage or setBackgroundColor, which one is better in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I might get down-votes for this question but i am curios and couldn't find any explanation. So I am gonna post it here.

My question is, I have to show custom separator image in my custom cell. If I simply set background colour of `imageView`, rather than setting `UIImage`, is it better approach?

Here is the example screenshot to explain my question.

[image]

In this screenshot, I have black and grey separators.

```
[barImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[greyBarImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyColor]];
```

OR

```
[barImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black.png"]];
[greyBarImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey.png"]];
```

Now, which one is better? All I know the `imageNamed:` is bit slower and we should avoid, but I am not sure about that.

**EDIT:**

This is what I know after posting this question:

Setting Image:

- It will cost the RAM
- Image will not cover the whole imageView, so there might be un-opaque portions on `UIImageView`

Setting background colour:

- This is an overhead on CPU but will decrease app memory.
- Background colour will cover the whole `UIImageView`, so the whole `imageView` will be opaque and will respond to touches.

Comment: If you're just setting background color, it would be better to use `UIView` instead of `UIImageView`.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev Could you explain why UIView will be better instead of UIImageView, don't know about it thats why i want to know.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh because `UIView` is easer then `UIImageView` in it's implementation, so it requires less time to draw. That means that if you're crazy about code performance (like questioner), the choice is obvious.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev Thanks, got your point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If both solution works for you the  setting background colour would be better than setting image

```
[barImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[greyBarImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyColor]];
```

> As this will
>
> 1.Save your app resources(Image).
>
> 2.Avoid runtime image loading issue(in case of rename replace).

Please refer [Simple drawing app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit) 
and [Image drawing app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/69855/image-processing-in-ios-part-1-raw-bitmap-modification).

Comment: But why use an image view at all if there is no image?

Comment: I agree with you, but that will increase CPU utilisation for setting background colour. Yet, we have to bear one overhead, RAM or CPU.

Comment: @AvijitNagare there should be proof that shows that drawing lines is really faster then picking an image up.

Answer (score 1):

Change background color would be better because:-

1. It will take less memory as compare to load image.
2. If you are going to set image in that case code will be runtime while you are using only color in that case code will be at compile time.
3. It will be faster as compare to load image.
   You can see live example in the given images:-

If we are going to change only background color it is faster and taking less memory

[image]

[image]

Or it would be much better if you are going to change only background color in that case you have to use `UIView` instead of `UIImageView` .

Answer (score 1):

One specific change that the final user can see is that if the cell can be selected/highlighted, if you use a background color that separator view will lose its background when selected.

If you use an image that view will Keep the same look&feel when touched.

If you care about that, go for the image, if not, go for the background color, it's easier to understand, tweak and it probably eats up less resources (depending on your image).

Answer (score 0):

To set custom separator color on tableview cell, you can simply specify the color of the separator you want by

```
[tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

Incase if you want to show alternate colours add the above statement in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method and differentiate using `indexPath` parameter.

Comment: `[tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor grayColor]];` this will not work for custom separator.